# How to hide current path and user and computer name in ubuntu terminal

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I want to hide the current path, user and computer name in the terminal in order to have more space.

Currently, in my terminal, it echoes: 
"user@computername:~/currentdirectoy" 
and I want to hide all of them since I don't need them.

ubuntu version:18.04 Desktop

[Screen shot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eId3i.png)

Answer (score 4):

For my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS works in the next way:
.- Find the *bashrc*

```
ls -la ~/ | more
```

.- Editing the file:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

.- Replace the w for W:
Before:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

After:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W\$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that:

1- you can modify it by entering

```
    PS1="something you want including static text and variables"
```

, but it would change back to the default as soon as you open a new terminal.

2- You can change it permanently for the current user by editing the ~/.bashrc file and changing all the PS1 = something to what you want. I just add "#" in front of all the current PS1 lines to comment it out and then wrote my own.

here is a  [good source:](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-prompt-basics) to find out more about bash conventions and variables.